# How can I skip ssl.truststore.password property while reading from Kafka using Spark Structured streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ssl, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read from Kafka and write to Kudu Sink using Spark Structured Streaming.
Below is the code for read and write.

I am using Spark 2.2.0.

```
val kafkaDataFrame = spark
  .readStream
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaReaderConfig.kafka_brokers)
  .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
  .option("kafka.sasl.mechanism" , "GSSAPI")
  .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", kafkaReaderConfig.trust_jks_file_path)
  .option("kafka.sasl.jaas.config", jaas_config_str)
  .option("subscribe", kafkaReaderConfig.topics_set)
  .load()
  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as value")

//After Transformation

  dfStrm.writeStream
    .option("checkpointLocation",path)
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("10 seconds"))
    .foreach(new KuduStreamWriter(tconfig))
    .outputMode("append")
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()
})
```

But getting the below exceptions:

```
20/05/07 10:59:00 INFO authenticator.AbstractLogin: Successfully logged in.
20/05/07 10:59:00 INFO kerberos.KerberosLogin: TGT refresh thread started.
20/05/07 10:59:00 INFO kerberos.KerberosLogin: TGT valid starting at: Thu May 07 10:58:17 UTC 2020
20/05/07 10:59:00 INFO kerberos.KerberosLogin: TGT expires: Thu May 07 20:58:16 UTC 2020
20/05/07 10:59:00 INFO kerberos.KerberosLogin: TGT refresh sleeping until: Thu May 07 19:25:22 UTC 2020
20/05/07 10:59:00 ERROR streaming.StreamExecution: Query [id = 6d08d948-6c28-4282-b108-eac99c62e253, runId = 94d599d9-b7a1-4cdc-937f-8d98390fb509] terminated with error
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:702)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:557)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:540)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.SubscribeStrategy.createConsumer(ConsumerStrategy.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader.createConsumer(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:297)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaOffsetReader.<init>(KafkaOffsetReader.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createSource(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSource(DataSource.scala:243)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:158)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1.apply(StreamExecution.scala:155)
        at scala.collection.mutable.MapLike$class.getOrElseUpdate(MapLike.scala:194)
        at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractMap.getOrElseUpdate(Map.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(StreamExecution.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(StreamExecution.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:266)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at 
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        .
        .
        .
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:304)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:272)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.logicalPlan$lzycompute(StreamExecution.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.logicalPlan(StreamExecution.scala:147)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runBatches(StreamExecution.scala:276)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:206)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: SSL trust store is specified, but trust store password is not specified.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:86)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:70)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:83)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:623)
        ... 370 more
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: SSL trust store is specified, but trust store password is not specified.
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.createTruststore(SslFactory.java:195)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.configure(SslFactory.java:115)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:83)
        ... 373 more
```

Q.1 Is there any way I can skip the the truststore.password property while reading from Kafka? (We don not have the password and also we do not need the password to work with Kafka)

Any suggestions or workarounds ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recommend you to update the version to 2.4.5

If you don't need SSL then don't set it.

```
val kafkaDataFrame = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaReaderConfig.kafka_brokers)
  .option("subscribe", kafkaReaderConfig.topics_set)
  .load()
  .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as value")
```

Comment: For now it is not feasible to upgrade the Spark Version. And SSL is needed .So we are providing the file. Values of ssl.truststore : ssl.truststore.type = JKS  ssl.truststore.location = /home/user/truststore.jks   ssl.truststore.password = null